# How to convert an iTextSharp.Image to vb .net MemoryStream

Tags: vb.net, itext

I'm having a little trouble with the **iTexSharp** library for **.Net**.
I want to generate a QR code and show the resulting image in a web page (or save it into a file, or wathever). Problem is, the class **BarcodeQRCode** only has the method **GetImage()** wich returns an **iTextShrap.text.image** object. From there I've tried to use the **RawData** property to create a **Memory Stream**, and that **Memory Stream** to create a **Bitmap**, but i get the ***Invalid Parameter*** Error. This is the code

```
1 Dim oQR As New BarcodeQRCode("DATA TO BE ENCODED", 1, 1, Nothing)
2 Dim oMS As New MemoryStream(oQR.GetImage().RawData)
3 Dim oBitmap As New Bitmap(oMS)
4 oBitmap.Save("C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\codigoQR.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
```

***(Error in line 3)***

So there seems to be a problem with the Byte Array RawData is returning. Does anyone know the correct way to do what i'm trying, or if I'm missing something?

Comment: See this for a work around. http://stackoverflow.com/q/4807749/231316

Comment: Thanks; I already did, but I don't want to rewrite the class. I ended up giving up on iTextSharp. I'm using a port of ZXing instead, i'ts working fine so far. https://zxingnet.codeplex.com/